# Limiting characters retrived from a database field

Tags: php, string, character, echo

I am a novice when it comes to PHP.

I am using Wordpress with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields), so any data I get from a field I use the code below:

```
echo $fieldname;
```

One of these fields is for information about something, what I want to do is limit the amount of characters retrieved so that only 150 character are displayed.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$str = "Aliquam odio eros, consectetur eu euismod faucibus, venenatis lobortis nulla. Pellentesque libero massa, bibendum in tempus ut, pretium et ante. In bibendum volutpat porta. ";

echo substr($str, 0, 150);
```

But if you have a long string, then you probaly want to cut it after an word. You can use the following function for this (it will cut of the str when it's to long and place the `...` behind it):

```
function truncate_string($str, $length) {
    if (!(strlen($str) <= $length)) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ' ', $length)) . '...';
    }

    return $str;
}
```

---

### **Client side**

You can also do it on the client side. 
I don't know what you try to achieve, but if it's an title or something and you don't want it to be too long and ruin your layout then you can use CSS3 `text-overflow`: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/V3c9V/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in PHP

```
$fieldname = substr($fieldname, 0, 150);
```

or just

```
echo substr($fieldname, 0, 150);
```

Alternatively, limit the number of characters that your database query returns, e.g. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and MS SQL both have a `LEFT(..)` function  which will restrict the data returned.

i.e.

```
SELECT LEFT(FieldName, 150) AS FieldName FROM MyTable WHERE ...
```

Comment: in your way you  are limiting the data after fetching from the database is there any way to limit while fetching ?

Comment: try this... @RegisteredUser
SELECT NAME,SUBJECT,LEFT(DESCRIPTION,50)AS SHORT_DESC FROM TABLENAME

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the cut so that you don't want to cut the sentence inside the word you can use this function:

```
function safeShrinkText($text, $length = 100, $suffix = '...')
{
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    if ($length > strlen($text)) {
        return $text;
    }

    while (!isset($text[$length]) || $text[$length] != ' ' && $length != 0) {
        $length--;
    }

    return mb_substr($text, 0, $length) . $suffix;
}
```

This function will not cut the sentence inside the word.

Comment: What part of the code would get the text from the field in the database? Do I still use a part from an earlier post in conjunction with this?   $str = ($about); echo substr($str,0, 150);

Comment: This function does not retrieve from database. It's just improved version of substr function. The difference between shrinkText and substr is that shrinkText will not cut insde the word. For example: shrinkText('Hello world!!!', 8, '...'); returns 'Hello...'.

Comment: When I use that code I get "annot redeclare shrinkText() (previously declared"

Comment: Originally I had this function in static class. I will edit and change it's name. thank you.